# How is a private IPFS network setup?

Tags: ipfs

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-89:~$ export LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET=1 && IPFS_PATH=~/.ipfs ipfs daemon
```

I have the following error -

```
export LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET=1 && IPFS_PATH=~/.ipfs ipfs daemon

 go1.11.1
Successfully raised file descriptor limit to 2048.
13:37:13.509 ERROR p2p-config: tried to create a libp2p node with no Private Network Protector but usage of Private Networks is forced by the enviroment config.go:69
13:37:13.512 ERROR   cmd/ipfs: error from node construction:  privnet: private network was not configured but is enforced by the environment daemon.go:332
Error: privnet: private network was not configured but is enforced by the environment
Received interrupt signal, shutting down...
(Hit ctrl-c again to force-shutdown the daemon.)
```

Any ideas about the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I carefully repeated the process and regenerated the swarm keys and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, when I tried to run it off a systemd service. Using the `LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET` env variable raises the error. I deleted the ipfs(~/.ipfs) data directory and run the init command again.

I think the reason could be the fact that I did not add the IPFS swarm key. Here's the commands if someone has a similar problem.

```
export LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET=1
IPFS_PATH=~/.ipfs ipfs init

#then,

go get -u github.com/Kubuxu/go-ipfs-swarm-key-gen/ipfs-swarm-key-gen
ipfs-swarm-key-gen > ~/.ipfs/swarm.key

IPFS_PATH=~/.ipfs ipfs daemon
```

Comment: Shoudl I apply this for all the nodes that are connected into the network

Comment: @alper You need to generate the key on one node and copy it over to the others before starting the daemon

Comment: Thanks , should I also delete the `~/.ipfs` data directory for all the nodes as well after pasting the key ?  because your first paragraph is not clear that deletint `~/.ipfs` is mandotary or not

Comment: @alper If I remember correctly yes, you'd have to delete the directory. My answer assumes you're doing it the first time you set up your cluster.

Comment: Deleting the `~/.ipfs` seems like a not a good solution since it will remove all the downloaded files on the public domain. Instead changing `IPFS_PATH` to new one something like, `~/.ipfs_private` and apply `ipfs init` seems safer to because original `~/.ipfs` won't be removed and users can switch in between based on their usage